# How to implement CyberSource REST 3D Secure

Tags: rest, 3d-secure, cybersource

I'm trying to implement 3D Secure via CyberSource's REST API. I've got their REST SDK via : [Github REST SDK](https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-samples-csharp) and I've been using their Live Console examples as well: [CyberSource Live Console](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments)

Now I know you meant to start by setting up Payer Auth via [image]

On this link: [Setup Payer API Ref](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payer-authentication_payer-authentication_setup-payer-auth_samplerequests-dropdown)

But want I'm looking for is a guide on how all the parts are put together, all their other older implementations seem to have PDF guides demonstrating the different flows of the API but I can't find anything for REST. I know at the end I should using the example of "*Authorization with Payer Auth Validation*" via this link [Payer Auth API Ref](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_process-a-payment_samplerequests-dropdown_authorization-with-payer-authentication_authorization-with-pa-enroll-authentication-needed) but I need to be able to test everything, and know what properties I need to use on which API call or share between API calls.

For instance like this 3D Secure API guide: [Sage Pay API Guide](https://developer.sage.com/api/payments/additional-integrations/3-D-secure/) . On this guide they detail the various request and response messages. Different flows, such as Frictionless authentication , Challenge Auth. I'm specifically interest in the Challenge Auth flow whereby you would redirect your customer to the acsUrl received. If anyone has any guides or assistance they can provide to make this process more clear it would be greatly appreciated. We've put in requests for more information from the intermediary party we are using between CyberSource but it's slow going. Thanx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is not a guide for the REST API that has the complete picture. Instead you have to use the SOAP API guide here [SOAP Guide](https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SO_API/Payer_Authentication_SO_API.pdf). See Chapter 2 within that guide. Where that guide references SOAP API calls replace them with the REST API calls. It's not ideal but that is all that is available.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback Will! Let me check that guide out and try mix and match. Will post again if I need any further assistance. Any idea when a guide will be updated for REST?  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else arriving here, there is now a CyberSource 3D-Secure REST guide [here](https://docs.cybersource.com/content/dam/new-documentation/documentation/en/fraud-management/payer-auth/rest/payer-auth-rest.pdf).

Comment: Thanx dude! I managed to get all my stuff working how I wanted via REST but it was a mission without a guide